# duplicate table (identical) including primary key - using django south

Tags: python, django, django-south, database-migration

I'm using south data migration to move data from one table to another (between django apps)

Its moving all the data as it suppose to but, problem is its not duplication the primary key (ID), instead creating a new one (in the new table) which make sense..

But how can I make a new table identical, including the id field (which is default, not defined in models)

using mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the table using `LIKE` in `forwards` part, insert everything from old table to the new one. In `backwards` part just drop the new table.

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table")
    db.execute("INSERT new_table SELECT * old_table")

def backwards(self, orm):
    db.drop_table('new_table')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hmm when we use 'LIKE' does it take cares of ForeignKey and separate tables in case of ManyToManyField?

Comment: I'm afraid it won't create separate tables for ManyToMany. Foreign keys are copied as is.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways to do what you want to do:

1. Write a multi-step migration.
2. Loop through rows and set ids.

I think the second is easier, although I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you are already writing something like

```
for a in A.objects.all():
    b = B(attr1 = a.attr1, ...)
    b.save()
```

then can't you simply write

```
b = B(id = a.id, attr1 = a.attr1, ...)
```

If you are using a more automatic way of copying your rows, consider the multi-step migration approach:
1. Write models A and B as so:

```
  class A(model):
      real_data = CharField()
  class B(model):
      real_data = CharField()
      fake_id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
      id = IntegerField()
```

1. Write a datamigration copying A to B
2. Write a schemamigration making B.id a primary_key and deleting fake_id

Comment: hmm "b = B(id = a.id, attr1 = a.attr1, ...)" should work, I haven't tried this! I end up using LIKE as per @alecxe answer.